# Javascript/typescript property decorator that mimics @NSManaged

Tags: javascript, typescript, parse-platform, decorator

I have been experimenting with Swift/Parse and now want to convert my code to React / ReactNative / Parse-React to see if this can be done.

In Swift, one can extend PFObject and have @NSManaged applied to properties to handle setting the managed properties for Parse.

```
open class FooModel: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    open class func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "FooModel"
    }
    @NSManaged open var name: String
}
```

I have attempted to do the same with the following Javascript decorator but it doesn't appear to be working as expected.  The decorator is being called and the appropriate 'set(key, val)' is being called, but the value is not being saved to my Parse server.

Is this even possible?  Am I missing something?

Thanks

```
var Parse = require('parse/react-native');

// function NSManaged(target, property, descriptor) {
function NSManaged<T>(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) {
    return {
        set: function (value) {
            if ( target instanceof Parse.Object ) {
                target.set( propertyKey, value, {
                    error: function(obj, error) {
                        console.log( 'the set failed: ' + error);
                        }
                    });
                console.log('target: ' + target.constructor.name + ' property: ' + propertyKey + ' value: ' + value);
            } else {
                console.log( 'target is not an instanceof Parse.Object');
            }
        },
        get: function() {
            let val = target.get( propertyKey);
            console.log('get', val);
            return val;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    };
  };

export class FooModel extends Parse.Object {
    @NSManaged
    name?: string

    constructor() {
        // @ts-ignore
        super('FooModel');
    }

}


let foo = new FooModel();
foo.name = "test";
foo.set( "name2", "test" );
foo.save();
```

Comment: I can't test right now, but your code contains an obvious error, you set the value on `target`. `target` is the class, not an instance of the class. You should use `this` inside the `set`/`get` functions to access the instance.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Titian's response, I changed my code to the following which appears to work to my expectations.  'name' and 'name2' are being saved to my Parse Server.

```
function NSManaged<T>(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) {
    return {
        set: function (value) {
            if ( target instanceof Parse.Object ) {
                this.set( propertyKey, value, {
                    error: function(obj, error) {
                        console.log( 'the set failed: ' + error);
                        }
                    });
            } else {
                console.log( 'target is not an instanceof Parse.Object');
            }
        },
        get: function() {
            let val = this.get( propertyKey);
            console.log('get', val);
            return val;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    };
  };
```